# Finding cause of horizontal scroll on bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### **This issue has been fixed thanks to Manoj Kumar**

I can't for the life of me fix the root cause of whitespace on the right side of a site I'm currently building, causing the dreaded 'accidental horizontal scrollbar.' It's especially noticeable on mobile.

http://bradfordkolumbic.com/ma/v2/

I've tried every trick I can think of. Using overflow-x: hidden on the body somewhat fixes the issue but I'm not at all about band-aid fixes - I'm attempting to find the full solution.

Comment: Can't see any whitespace on the right..

Comment: There is something wrong with your markup here, The problem is with the container div, still trying to figure out what it is though

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I'm still pulling my hair out trying to figure out where the issue is. Another user made some good suggestions but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @BradfordKolumbic Are you getting the problem even now?  I can debug your site again and improve my solution if it is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems, each with your markup and style sheet.

1. First you need to remove this:

   ```
   .info-box {
     padding: 20px 0 40px;
   }
   ```

The above code is overriding the default padding of the `col-*` classes which was by default added to compensate for the negative margins provided by `row` classes.

2. and then in the below code:

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="container-fluid text-center partners"></div> 
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   You have wrapped a `container-fluid` element within a `row` element, while you need to do the reverse.

   [**Bootstrap grid documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

   > Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
   >   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, after disabling the info-box and fixing the container-fluid row issue, the problem still persists.

I've actually gone through and deleted every element to see exactly where the issue is being caused but even then I can't seem to find it. I went from top to bottom, switching things on and off and nothing seems to be the culprit. It's a if the actual body of the page somewhere is causing an issue.

Comment: I guess the problem is gone now. I can't see the scroll bar on any screen size.

Comment: Manoj, your solution worked great actually. For some reason it didn't work at first but it turned out to be a weird caching issue on my server that resulted in the CSS not being properly updated. 

I've marked your answer as accepted. Thank you so much!